# What is a fast reset in Blackberry?

Tags: java, events, blackberry

I am not the only one who wonders, as can be seen at the [blackberry support forums](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/What-is-Fast-Reset/m-p/630455).

There's a method on `SystemListener2` called [`fastReset()`](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.2api/net/rim/device/api/system/SystemListener2.html#fastReset%28%29) with this documentation:

> Invoked when a fast reset occurs.

However there's no information on what a fast reset is!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a quick reset

<s>http://www.blackberrytips.net/miscellaneous/How_To_Reboot_Your_BlackBerry/</s>
http://my.ads4click.com/faqs/blackberry-faqs/how-to-fast-reboot-your-blackberry/

You can do a quick reset, but press Alt + Caps + Del.

You know you want to do a quick reset, when you would otherwise feel the urge to pull the battery.